# Bootstrap3 Image Below Caption, Rescale Image To Fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm creating a simple carousel with HTML and JS. I have it mostly how I want it to look now, unfortunately there are a few issues:

**Running The Snippet:**

1) I want the caption to be in the space below the image, not on it. I've done what I can with CSS based on my minor skills and can't figure it out.

2) Also, I want the pictures resized and centred so the fit into the carousel, instead of most of it being cropped out.

**Carousel Juts Out**

1) I've made the website responsive, and the container has `style="text-align:center;text-align: justify;"`. However if you look at the image below, in some cases when the browser window is minimised,the carousel juts out. How do I resolve this?

[image]

```css
.carousel-caption {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -95px;
}

.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

#serviceSlider .item {
  height: 400px;
}

#slide1{
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/31/19/20/dog-4988985_960_720.jpg'); center no-repeat;
}

#slide2{
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg'); center no-repeat;
}

#slide3{
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/09/22/44/piglet-3386356_960_720.jpg'); center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .carousel-inner>.item>img,
    .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>

    <div class="container" style="text-align:center;text-align: justify;">
      <br>
      <div id="serviceSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#serviceSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#serviceSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#serviceSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active" id="slide1">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Dog</h3>
              <p>Cute Corgi.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item" id="slide2">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Cat</h3>
              <p>Cute cat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item" id="slide3">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Pigs</h3>
              <p>Sleepy pigs.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#serviceSlider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#serviceSlider" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do much just make some changes in class of caption carousel. Try copy and pasting to see if it works. No additional changes in css.

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/31/19/20/dog-4988985_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/31/19/20/dog-4988985_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/31/19/20/dog-4988985_960_720.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nargesh. This seems to work! Would you happen to know how to solve the issue of the carousel jutting out of the container too?

Comment: add entire code for the container/div your putting carousel into. By default carousal takes entire page width.

Comment: Before container add a div with col-md-12. That should keep things inside. Also it depends how you have structure html. If the carousel is under container it should stay with container on zoom.